# Windows Task Scheduler to minimize running program and maximize another program

Tags: windows

I have two programs running the same time on Windows 10 PC, is there any way I can set Task Scheduler to Minimize open program and Maximize another program and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible: task scheduling is about automating certain tasks, as if in background. Minimising and maximising windows is about working in an interactive way.

You might check `schtasks /?` and `schtasks /create /?`: this gives you a full overview of all possibilities of task scheduling, and I don't find any clue on window maximising or minimising.